# How to query in database with GraphQL where to pluck only selected fields not all fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, graphql

I want to know if we can query to pluck selected columns and the request to the database to search for only those selected columns not the whole data at the endpoint. If there is any confusion in this question please let me know.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work? Please share some relevant code that you have.

Comment: i have added the screenshots in the question of my type file, resolver file, the postman query and its response the query plucks everything from database and show only the fields which are queried but i want it to do query only on the selected fields in the database.